# How is this effect created in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I'm new to Photoshop and I am looking for hints or a tutorial to create images with a style like in this magazine:

http://www.curves-magazin.com/de/Blog/Col-de-la-Musique

I especially like color and detail of these images.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Push the colour temperature and fill light sliders all the way up in lightroom (or google HDR tutorial).

Comment: @MattGrum Note that the [fill light slider](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2012/03/what-happened-to-fill-light-and-recovery.html) doesn't exist in LR 4+ (strictly, in process version 2012 and later).

Comment: Cranking up Clarity would do the trick pretty well I would think.

Comment: Can you please help us by providing a title and body text which describe the effect and what you like about the "color and detail" and how you see these images as unique in that way? See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: Also, warning: link plays music without prompting. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the saturation was cranked up considerably, contrast a bit higher than "normal", and the whites allowed to clip a little.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to find the Photoshop functions to play with.